# Use a executable if it exists, otherwise, use another

Tags: docker, docker-compose, makefile

As you know may noticed, Docker changed the name of compose from `docker-compose` to `docker compose`

I have a Makefile that calls docker-compose

```
run:
    docker-compose up --build
```

However I want to make my Makefile portable, I was wondering if it is possible to the Makefile first tries if `docker-compose` exists, if not, uses `docker compose`

Is it possible?

Comment: Is this GNU or BSD make? i.e. what's the output of `make --version`?

Comment: GNU Make 4.2.1, but I want most portable possible if possible

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want it to be the most portable then you'd implement it in the shell, something like:

```
run:
        test -n "$$(command -v docker-compose)" \
            && docker-compose up --build \
            || docker compose up --build
```

If you're willing to use make-specific features you can do something a bit fancier such as:

```
ifeq ($(shell command -v docker-compose;),)
    COMPOSE := docker compose
else
    COMPOSE := docker-compose
endif

run:
        $(COMPOSE) up --build
```